# Python: Replacing particular values with the average of their neighbors without loops

Tags: python, arrays

For example in this list:

```
arr = [1.0, 1.0, None, 3.0, None, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, None, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
```

I need to replace all the `None`'s with the average of their neighbors, **without using loops or additional functions** (only `lambda`) .

This should be the result:

```
[1.0, 1.0, **2.0**, 3.0, **4.0**, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, **3.0**, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
```

I tried to do this by using `map`:

```
arr = list(map(lambda x: (arr[arr.index(None) - 1] + arr[arr.index(None) + 1]) / 2 if not x else x, arr))
```

The problem is that `arr.index(None)` is called only once and returns `2`, instead of calculating the next `None`'s index.
So in this way the result is:

```
[1.0, 1.0, **2.0**, 3.0, **2.0**, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, **2.0**, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: assume that None can't appear at the begging or the end .
      Also Nones can't appear in row.

Comment: Are you allowed to use `enumerate`? Bit puzzled as to what on earth this is supposed to teach you if it's an assignment...

Comment: What is the desired result if there are 2 (or more) None next to each other?

Comment: I'd personally try writing this in a sane way using whatever functions you need. Then work through how you could collapse it to your bizarre constraints...

Comment: What is supposed to happen, if `None` appears at the beginning or the end of the list?

Comment: I guess i'm allowed to use enumerate , but i can't figure out how can it help me ..

Comment: I was told to assume that None can't appear at the beginning or the end..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you showed could be solved for example by the following:

```
arr = [1.0, 1.0, None, 3.0, None, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, None, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
indices = range(1, len(arr)-1)

arr_new = [arr[0]] + list(map(lambda i: (arr[i-1] + arr[i+1])/2 if arr[i] is None else arr[i], indices)) + [arr[-1]]
print arr
print arr_new
```

BUT: You did not clarify yet what should happen if the first or last element is `None` or two elements next to each other are `None`, therefore these cases will fail here.

Output:

```
[1.0, 1.0, None, 3.0, None, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, None, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
[1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
```

Comment: Thank you so much !